# how to create menu in angular 11 by inputing array from parent to child

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a menu with 2 tabs, I defined this array in parent

```
public labelArray: string[]=[''];

  constructor() { 
  this.labelArray =['tab1', 'tab2'];
}
```

I called this array in child component

```
@Input('tabs') public labelArray: any;
```

then I put this in child.html

```
<div>
  {{labelArray}}
</div>
```

and then use ngFor to iterate the array index

```
<div class="header-menu">
        <app-tabs [tabs]= "labelArray" *ngFor= 'let item of labelArray'></app-tabs>
```

but the resulted menu is like this:  tab1,tab2  tab1,tab2

it should be like this: tab1 tab2

how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use *ngFor in Parent component.

```
<app-tabs [tabs]= "labelArray"></app-tabs>
```

If you want to use *ngFor, then use it in child component:

```
<div *ngFor= 'let item of labelArray'>
  {{item}}
</div>
```

Comment: but it shows the menu like this: tab1,tab2   I mean there is a comma between two tab, i want to it shows an empty menu at first and then by using ngFor put 2 item in the menu